# Vector initialization in C++17

Tags: c++, vector, c++17

When I compile this code with C++17 it works well, but any version other than C++17 it throws an error [tried with C++14]:

> error: missing template arguments before ‘v’
>       vector v {1, 2, 3};

Here is the code snippet I am using:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using std::vector;
using std::cout;

int main() {

    // Vector initialization
    vector v {1, 2, 3};

    for (int i=0; i < v.size(); i++) {
      cout << v[i] << "\n";
    }
}
```

Has `std::vector` declaration and/or initialization changed in C++17? Can anyone explain why C++17 compiles this vector initialization (as intended) without any error?

Comment: Well yes, you need a template argument before `v` as in `std::vector<int> v { 1, 2, 3};`. And yes this has changed in C++17, cf. [Class template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Prior to C++17 you MUST specify vector's type through template:

```
std::vector<int> v{1, 2, 3};
```

C++17 instead allows for "deduction", which is why your code compiles even without specifying the type contained in your vector. You can read more about it [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction).

Generally I'd suggest to specify the type for readability even if deduction would do what you want it to.

Comment: I disagree with your suggestion.

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann i'd like to know what makes relying on deduction better than explicitly telling to the reader the exact type that's being used.

Comment: As a good practice and to make my code more robust, should I use template argument deduction in my code or not?

Comment: @Deep my point is that writing the type anyone who is reading your code will instantly know what your vector is containing and what you're dealing with, without having to think about it too much. But i want to know Micha's point of view too.

Comment: @Barnack: "*i'd like to know what makes relying on deduction better than explicitly telling to the reader the exact type that's being used.*" The reader can easily see what type is being used in this case. Redundant information is redundant.

Comment: Relying on deduction has two camps:  those in favor, those opposed.  (Like spaces vs tabs, where the curly braces go, or vim vs emacs.)  If you are on a team, use whichever your team prefers.

Comment: 1. Eljay is 100 % correct, this topic is subjective rather than objective, i.e. there is no best way, only consequences. 2. Things I like about type deduction: removes redundancy; in code with lots of template arguments it feels to be in my way; I like what I have seen in Haskell. Things I don't like: In situations where I want to know the type it becomes more difficult to get this information and might rely on IDE/tooling support. But essentially Eljay.